# How to specify reporter-options in CLI for specific reporter module being used with cypress-multi-reporters?

Tags: cypress

I am using the cypress-multi-reporters npm module to generate both a JUnit report and an html report using the mocha-junit-reporter and mochawesome modules respectively. I am trying to specify the mochawesome `reportFilename` value via the cli to accommodate multiple tests that require specific file names but can't figure out how to achieve this.

At the moment the Cypress tests are run via a shell script containing commands that looks like this:

```
cypress-ntlm run --reporter cypress-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=reporter-config.json --spec cypress/sometest1.feature

cypress-ntlm run --reporter cypress-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=reporter-config.json --spec cypress/sometest2.feature
```

My reporter-config.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome, mocha-junit-reporter",
        "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
            "reportDir": "cypress/integration/reports",
            "reportFilename": "Test",
            "overwrite": false,
            "html": true,
            "json": false
        },
        "mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
            "mochaFile": "cypress/results/results-[hash].xml"
        }
}
```

This works fine, but I need the html reports generated by mochawesome to have specific filenames declared in my shell script. This was easily doable before I started using the cypress-multi-reporters module with the following commands:

```
cypress-ntlm run --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options reportFilename='specific-filename' --spec cypress/sometest.feature

cypress-ntlm run --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options reportFilename='another-specific-filename' --spec cypress/sometest2.feature
```

Is anyone aware of any way to achieve this using the cypress-multi-reporters module? I've scoured the documentation and am not having much luck. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was looking to use both XML and Mochawesome but could not figure it out. Your question solved mine!